# Interface as argument, returning result

Tags: java, function, methods, lambda, java-8

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Moves in squared strings (I)](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56dbe0e313c2f63be4000b25). The statement is:

> You are given a string of n lines, each substring being n characters
>   long: For example:
>
> s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
>
> We will study some transformations of this square of strings.
>
> ```
> Vertical mirror: vert_mirror (or vertMirror or vert-mirror)
>
> vert_mirror(s) => "dcba\nhgfe\nlkji\nponm"
>
> Horizontal mirror: hor_mirror (or horMirror or hor-mirror)
>
> hor_mirror(s) => "mnop\nijkl\nefgh\nabcd"
> ```
>
> or printed:
>
> vertical mirror   |horizontal mirror    abcd --> dcba     |abcd -->
>   mnop  efgh     hgfe     |efgh     ijkl  ijkl     lkji     |ijkl
>   efgh  mnop     ponm     |mnop     abcd
>
> ## Task:
>
> ```
> Write these two functions
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> high-order function oper(fct, s) where
>     fct is the function of one variable f to apply to the string s (fct will be one of vertMirror, horMirror)
> ```
>
> ## Examples:
>
> s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop" oper(vert_mirror, s) =>
>   "dcba\nhgfe\nlkji\nponm" oper(hor_mirror, s) =>
>   "mnop\nijkl\nefgh\nabcd"

I would like some help because of it is the first time I need to pass functions as method's arguments. The initial test cases are (taken from the exercise):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class OpstringsTest {

    private static void testing(String actual, String expected) {
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Fixed Tests vertMirror");
        String s = "hSgdHQ\nHnDMao\nClNNxX\niRvxxH\nbqTVvA\nwvSyRu";
        String r = "QHdgSh\noaMDnH\nXxNNlC\nHxxvRi\nAvVTqb\nuRySvw";
        testing(Opstrings.oper(Opstrings::vertMirror, s), r);
        s = "IzOTWE\nkkbeCM\nWuzZxM\nvDddJw\njiJyHF\nPVHfSx";
        r = "EWTOzI\nMCebkk\nMxZzuW\nwJddDv\nFHyJij\nxSfHVP";
        testing(Opstrings.oper(Opstrings::vertMirror, s), r);

        System.out.println("Fixed Tests horMirror");
        s = "lVHt\nJVhv\nCSbg\nyeCt";
        r = "yeCt\nCSbg\nJVhv\nlVHt";        
        testing(Opstrings.oper(Opstrings::horMirror, s), r);
        s = "njMK\ndbrZ\nLPKo\ncEYz";
        r = "cEYz\nLPKo\ndbrZ\nnjMK";
        testing(Opstrings.oper(Opstrings::horMirror, s), r);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following implementation:

```
import java.util.function.*;
class Opstrings {    
  public static String vertMirror (String string) {
    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word : words){
      sb.append(new StringBuilder(word).reverse()+"\n");
    }
    return string.strip().toString();
  }
  public static String horMirror (String string) {
    return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
  }
  public static String oper/*️*/(Consumer<String> operator, String s) {
    return operator.accept(s);
  }
}
```

And when we execute the previous code, the compiler outputs:

> ./src/main/java/Opstrings.java:15: error: incompatible types: void
>   cannot be converted to String
>       return operator.accept(s);
>                             ^ 1 error

I understand that Consumer is defined to return void. So then I decided to investigate and I read that Callable is able to return results. So then I tried:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
class Opstrings {    
  public static String vertMirror (String string) {
    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word : words){
      sb.append(new StringBuilder(word).reverse()+"\n");
    }
    return string.strip().toString();
  }
  public static String horMirror (String string) {
    return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
  }
  public static String oper/*️*/(Callable operator, String s) {
    return operator.accept(s);
  }
}
```

However this time our compiler says that we can not call the functions without arguments when String is required (from the test cases):

> ./src/test/java/OpstringsTest.java:14: error: incompatible types:
>   invalid method reference
>           testing(Opstrings.oper(Opstrings::vertMirror, s), r);
>                                  ^
>       method vertMirror in class Opstrings cannot be applied to given types
>         required: String
>         found: no arguments
>         reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length ./src/test/java/OpstringsTest.java:17: error: incompatible types:
>   invalid method reference

In addition, I have also read:

- [How to pass a function as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-consumer-interface-in-java-with-examples/
- [Returning Method value inside a Consumer expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676196/returning-method-value-inside-a-consumer-expression)
- [Java 8 lambda Void argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945627/java-8-lambda-void-argument)
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-runnable-callable
- https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-callable-interface-y-su-uso/

Could you help me please figuring out how could we pass in Functional Interfaces as method's arguments and return its results?

EDIT: As @JB Nizet says it can be done using UnaryOperator:

```
import java.util.function.*;

class Opstrings {    
  public static String vertMirror (String string) {
    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
      words[i] = new StringBuilder(words[i]).reverse().toString();
    }
    return String.join("\n",words);
  }

  public static String horMirror (String string) {
    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = words.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      sb.append(words[i]+"\n");
    }
    return sb.toString().strip();
  }

  public static String oper/*️*/(UnaryOperator<String> operator, String s) {
    return operator.apply(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Consumer` is a function from someting to nothing (void). `Callable` is a function from nothing to something. You want a function from something to something else.

That's what [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is for. Or, since the return type and the argument type are the same in your case, [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html).